# Как устранить ошибку Unknown format , attempted to normalize to 0x

Tags: python-3.x, web3.py

Тестирую код на винде и падает с ошибкой:

```
←[37m
/// start check balance...←[0m
←[37m1. 0x6590ea1E7833846D2D73c3191275508f04B36d8e : 0←[0m
←[37m2. 0xD10200551f6dFaa408270FdbfBee660A636bcFE2 : 0←[0m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programms\BOT\BINANCE WITHDRAW\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    address = web3.toChecksumAddress(wallet)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\main.py", line 226, in toChecksumAddress
    return to_checksum_address(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\address.py", line 114, in to_checksum_address
    norm_address = to_normalized_address(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\address.py", line 68, in to_normalized_address
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unknown format , attempted to normalize to 0x
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Сам код:

```
 import time
 import ccxt
 from termcolor import cprint
 from web3 import Web3
 import random

def check_balance(address, number, web3):
try:
    balance = web3.eth.get_balance(web3.toChecksumAddress(address))
    humanReadable = web3.fromWei(balance,'ether')
    cprint(f'{number}. {address} : {humanReadable}', 'white')

except Exception as error:
    cprint(f'{number}. {address} = {error}', 'red')

def binance_withdraw(address, amount_to_withdrawal, symbolWithdraw, network, API_KEY, API_SECRET):

account_binance = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': API_KEY,
    'secret': API_SECRET,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'spot'
    }
})

try:
    account_binance.withdraw(
        code = symbolWithdraw,
        amount = amount_to_withdrawal,
        address = address,
        tag = None, 
        params = {
            "network": network
        }
    )
    cprint(f">>> Успешно | {address} | {amount_to_withdrawal}", "green")
except Exception as error:
    cprint(f">>> Неудачно | {address} | ошибка : {error}", "red")

if __name__ == "__main__":

with open("wallets.txt", "r") as f:
    wallets_list = [row.strip() for row in f]

symbolWithdraw = 'ETH'
network = 'Arbitrum'

# RPC = 'https://mainnet.optimism.io'
# RPC = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org'
# RPC = 'https://polygon-rpc.com'
RPC = 'https://arb1.arbitrum.io/rpc'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(RPC))

# api_keys of binance
API_KEY = "your_api_key"
API_SECRET = "your_api_secret"

cprint('\a\n/// start check balance...', 'white')
number = 0
for wallet in wallets_list:
    address = web3.toChecksumAddress(wallet)
    number = number + 1
    check_balance(address, number, web3) # проверяет баланс ETH

cprint('\a\n/// start withdrawing...', 'white')
for wallet in wallets_list:
    address = web3.toChecksumAddress(wallet)
    amount_to_withdrawal = round(random.uniform(0.001, 0.002), 6) # amount from ... to ...
    binance_withdraw(address, amount_to_withdrawal, symbolWithdraw, network, API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    time.sleep(random.randint(10, 30))
```

Comment: Это явно не весь стек-трейс. Приведите **полный текст ошибки**, все строки трейса. Там должна быть указана и строка вашего кода, в которой была ошибка, там, где вы вызвали библиотеку. А сейчас нужно догадываться - где в вашем коде проблема. То, что упала какая-то библиотека в какой-то строке - не даёт никаких намёков, в каком же месте вашего кода был вызов этой библиотеки, и какой именно вызов.

Comment: Добавление в теме

Comment: Ага, значит две строки нормально прошло, а что в третьей строке файла? Сделайте `print(wallet)` в начале цикла `for wallet in wallets_list:`, ну или в самом файле посмотрите. Может там пустая строка. А может что-то ещё, не подходящего формата.

Comment: И я не знаю насколько эти числа `0x...` секретные, не нужно их скрывать? Я конечно сам попросил вывод показать, но я не в курсе крипты как там чего, конкретика то мне не важна.

Comment: Это адреса кошельков, куда должна выводится денежка. Эти адреса она как раза берет из файла, то есть видно, что они начинаются с 0х. Кстати по строчкам вроде отрабатывает вывод (первые две строки), но по факту вывод не происходит.

Comment: Если это весь вывод на экран, то нет, до вывода из кошельков дело не доходит, падает на третьем адресе в файле, что бы там ни было. Перечитайте мой комментарий выше ещё раз внимательно. Если у вас там нет третьего адреса, значит там лишний перевод строки или что-то ещё.

Comment: Хорошо, сделайте print(wallets_list) после чтения файла и покажите, что получилось

Comment: Спасибо за подсказу. Проблема была в том, что текстовой курсор в файле с кошельками сохранился не в конце текста, а на новой строке, то есть по сути пустая с трока ...